# Partially exploding dataframe with nested lists items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the below format:

```
         A              B              C
0  [[1,2],[3,4]]  [[5,6],[7,8]]  [[9,10],[11,12]]
```

for multiple rows.
The sub lists are always of length 2 and the length of A,B,C lists are always the same size.However the lengths of the latter vary and for example can be of size 2 or 6..etc for different rows.

What i would like to do is to explode rows like these into:

```
         A              B              C
0      [1,2]          [5,6]          [9,10]
0      [3,4]          [7,8]          [11,12]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really have lists of lists, a simple `explode` on all columns should work:

```
df.explode(df.columns.to_list())
```

output:

```
        A       B         C
0  [1, 2]  [5, 6]   [9, 10]
0  [3, 4]  [7, 8]  [11, 12]
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]]]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```